# is their a way to start video from where we left in react js just like a youtube videos have

Tags: reactjs

I am building a project where pre recorded podcast episode will be uploaded but I have notice that when I am half way through a video and refresh page the video will play from beginning, I am    trying to find a solution if its possible to start video from where we left.

Comment: You could use local storage to store the current podcast and its playback time so it persists through reloads.

Comment: Yes. You just need to keep track of the current video time by listening to the timeupdate event, and store it in localStorage—preferably keyed by the video source.